# Migrate Users From laravel to wordpress

Tags: database, users, migration, password

we used Laravel before , and now we are moving to Wordpress, so we need to migrate all users including the passwords , is this possible?
thanks

Comment: Why would it not be possible?

Comment: Because of passwords cryptography

Comment: Good point you could have added to the question. Can you switch your application to use the same method WP uses? Or vice versa, make WP use the same method your Laravel app uses. Or ask users to re-enter passwords once when in the process of migrating.

Comment: yes im new here and im not a developer, so any more details it will help me lot with this process @kero, if i change the wp cryptography is this will have effects on some plugins that manage membership or something like this? ( by the way i dont know which is the better way to chage the wp cryptography ) , i apreciate your answers

Comment: I'm sorry, but this Q&A is mostly for developers - and your question should also be asked to developers. Who decided on the move from Laravel to WordPress? They should consider this, and ask their devs the appropriate questions.

Comment: Undrestood , thanks Kero